# Listview opening from bottom in android

Tags: android

I have a layout where I have to add something on top and then at bottom on list view so I don't want to scroll only I want to scroll only list view I want to scroll whole screen so I added this code.

//Remove scrolling from list view so that It scroll whole screen

```
 public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/body"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">






        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/header"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"


            >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:weightSum="2"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:text="RSHO Doses"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="#636363"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_Heading_Size"
                            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/rsho_drawable"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_Heading_Size"
                            android:text="Seizures"
                            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/seizures_drawable"

                            android:textColor="#636363"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"

                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:text="Events"
                            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:background="@color/colorHeadingBG"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_Heading_Size"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorHeading"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <ListView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
                            android:divider="#e5e5e5"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:id="@+id/listView"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>





    </LinearLayout>






</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

so when I open this application it remove scrolling from list view and add whole list view height in page but it always open from bottom. any solution for this

Comment: What you want is kind of confusing, try putting some commas or explaining better i will analyze for now.

Comment: I want to scrollwhole page not only listview and I am able to do that using above code but when I open the application it opens from bottom of the screen.Getting my point ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this setting.

```
listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
listView.setHasFixedSize(false);
```

This way the scroll of ListView will be disabled.

Comment: Ops, that is for recycler view.

Comment: as I told you I am able to stop the scrolling but when I open application it open from the bottom of list view